# how to pass variables to zendhelper class through ajax in zendframework 2?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

am new to zend framework2

I write helper class for calculating tax amount

I invoked the helper class from view.phtml like

```
$taxamount=$this->reznext_helper($hotelcode,$rackrate,$chargerate);
```

It's working fine but, I want to acces this function through ajax.

I hope any one help me to get solution for this.

Thanks you
kamatchi

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal jquery ajax or fancybox ajax iframe plugin.
This is example of Bootstrap Model dialogue which am used to access this link through ajax.

```
process = function(e)
 {
    var idvar = "#myModal";
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://zf.server/reznext/taxcalculator",
    data: $(e).serialize(),
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
    $('.modal-body').empty().append(msg);
    $(idvar).modal('show'); 
    });
 };
```